# I'm having trouble using window.scrollY on the mobile version of the website

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, responsive

I have a website that prints the current Y position to the console whenever the window is scrolled up or down. It works perfectly on the computer, even when I resize the window. However, when I access it on a mobile device or even in the mobile version of Chrome's developer mode, it does not print the value of window.scrollY. It remains at 0, even when scrolling down. However, it starts to appear when I reach approximately the middle of the page.:

````
function chama() {
        let posVert = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
        console.log(posVert);
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", chama);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", chama);
```[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYnGB.png)



I tried to create the same code with an empty HTML file, and it worked both on desktop and mobile. I believe there might be something in my HTML causing the issue, but I'm not sure what it is.
````